# For Loop checking player locations

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

This is a Bukkit plugin, for Minecraft, using their API.

I'm trying to check if a player is in a specified location, and if they are, then don't teleport a player there. Instead, check another location, and spawn the player there if it's empty.

It may be better explained by the code below:

```
Player player = (Player) sender;
List< Player> prisoners = new ArrayList< Player>();
for (int i = 0; i < prisoners.size(); i++) {
    //loc(1-12) are coords in the form of a location variable. I just wanted to save some room.
    if (!(loc1 == prisoners.get(i))) {
        player.teleport(loc1);
    } else if (!(loc1 == prisoners.get(i).getLocation())) {
        player.teleport(loc2);
    } else if (!(loc2 == prisoners.get(i).getLocation())) {
        player.teleport(loc3);
    } else if (!(loc3 == prisoners.get(i).getLocation())) {
        player.teleport(loc4);
    } else if (!(loc4 == prisoners.get(i).getLocation())) {
        player.teleport(loc5);
    } else if (!(loc5 == prisoners.get(i).getLocation())) {
        player.teleport(loc6);
    } else if (!(loc6 == prisoners.get(i).getLocation())) {
        player.teleport(loc7);
    } else if (!(loc7 == prisoners.get(i).getLocation())) {
        player.teleport(loc8);
    } else if (!(loc8 == prisoners.get(i).getLocation())) {
        player.teleport(loc9);
    } else if (!(loc9 == prisoners.get(i).getLocation())) {
        player.teleport(loc10);
    } else if (!(loc10 == prisoners.get(i).getLocation())) {
        player.teleport(loc11);
    } else if (!(loc11 == prisoners.get(i).getLocation())) {
        player.teleport(loc12);
    } else {
        player.sendMessage("Sorry, the Prisoner's team is full. Try joining the Guards, or wait until the next round.");
        player.teleport(lobby);
        prisoners.remove(player);
    }
```

I want to check each location, and teleport the player to the next available location by going through the list of players on the prisoner's team, and checking their location.

But, this doesn't seem to work, as I spawn in the same position, so how would I fix this issue?

I use virtual players to test with multiple players, instead of paying for accounts.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why are you using `==` to compare?

Comment: I just edited the post, below the code is the clearer question.

Comment: For the "Why are you using == to compare?", Eclipse gave me an error about the "!" operator being undefined.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `!=` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This condition

```
!(loc1 == prisoners.get(i))
```

will always evaluate to true as `loc1` as you say is a Co-ordinate and `prisoners.get(i)` is a `Player` object. These will never be equal so your above condition evaluates to

```
!(false)  // meaning true
```

So every iteration of the loop will execute `player.teleport(loc1);`

You need to use `.equals` not == and also make sure you are comparing two objects of the same type.